# group the json object by month, product and total product sale in a month

Tags: python, json, django, dataframe

my ouput:
"dataSource1": [
{
"date": "Oct-20",
"product": "A",
"sale": 10
},
{
"date": "Nov-20",
"product": "A",
"sale": 12
},
{
"date": "Oct-20",
"product": "B",
"sale": 12
},
{
"date": "Nov-20",
"product": "B",
"sale": 13
},
{
"date": "Oct-20",
"product": "C",
"sale": 13
},
{
"date": "Nov-20",
"product": "C",
"sale": 14
},

expected output:
{
"date": "Oct-20",
"A": 10,
"B": 12,
"C": 13,
},
{
"date": "NOV-20",
"A": 12,
"B": 13,
"C": 14,
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data =  [ { "date": "Oct-20", "product": "A", "sale": 10 }, { "date": "Nov-20", "product": "A", "sale": 12 }, { "date": "Oct-20", "product": "B", "sale": 12 }, { "date": "Nov-20", "product": "B", "sale": 13 }, { "date": "Oct-20", "product": "C", "sale": 13 }, { "date": "Nov-20", "product": "C", "sale": 14 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.pivot(df, values='sale', index=['date'], columns=['product']).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

|  | date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Nov-20 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 1 | Oct-20 | 10 | 12 | 13 |

`df.to_dict(orient='records')`:

`[{'A': 12, 'B': 13, 'C': 14, 'date': 'Nov-20'}, {'A': 10, 'B': 12, 'C': 13, 'date': 'Oct-20'}]`

If you wish to sort the dataframe by date:

```
import pandas as pd
data =  [ { "date": "Oct-20", "product": "A", "sale": 10 }, { "date": "Nov-20", "product": "A", "sale": 12 }, { "date": "Oct-20", "product": "B", "sale": 12 }, { "date": "Nov-20", "product": "B", "sale": 13 }, { "date": "Oct-20", "product": "C", "sale": 13 }, { "date": "Nov-20", "product": "C", "sale": 14 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y') # convert column to datetime objects
df = pd.pivot(df, values='sale', index=['date'], columns=['product']).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df = df.sort_values('date') # sort by datetime objects
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%b-%y') # reset datetime to original format
```

Output `df.to_dict(orient='records')`:

```
[{'date': 'Oct-20', 'A': 10, 'B': 12, 'C': 13}, {'date': 'Nov-20', 'A': 12, 'B': 13, 'C': 14}]
```

Another option is to use the dates as keys in the output dict:

```
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
```

Output `df.to_dict('index')`:

```
{'Oct-20': {'A': 10, 'B': 12, 'C': 13}, 'Nov-20': {'A': 12, 'B': 13, 'C': 14}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. I am new to python.

Comment: hi RJ Adriaansen, I have used it, it worked, but now another problem occurred. months are not in order. in dataframe it is showing months wise but in the pivot table dec month comes first rest of the order is correct, ex. Dec-20, jan-21, feb-21, nov-20, oct-20.

Comment: Sure, I've added a solution to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir. The first option is working. All the months are in sequence now. but in Ascending order. can we get it in Descending order.

Comment: Certainly: `df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=False)`

Comment: Such a quick response, Thanks a lot. I'm looking forward to you as a mentor now in this python journey. May I ask more questions from Now onwards?

Comment: Please post new questions to the main Stackoverflow page. There are many to help you out, I'm not always around.